# VBA to create several lists based on multiple columns and criteria

Tags: excel, vba, copy, criteria

I have two sheets, one input sheet with a large data set (Input SAP) and one sheet where I would like to list instances based on different criteria, but also in different categories (Output). I would want to push a button in the "Output" and get the different lists. In the below code, there are two lists, but there will be more.

The output sheet would be something like this: Column E would list all SAP numbers where column H in the input sheet is blank. Column G would list all SAP numbers where column O is equal to zero.

Column E gets populated correctly with the below code, but nothing happens to column G.I do not know how to fill several columns within the same sub.. I would also prefer not to make seperate row definitions since there will be approx. 10 different lists in the end.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     ReadIncomplete
   End Sub


   Private Sub ReadIncomplete()
   Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Output")
   Dim iws As Worksheet: Set iws = wb.Worksheets("Input SAP")

   irow = ws.Range("E7").Row
   RowNo = iws.Range("A2").Row


  Do Until iws.Cells(RowNo, 2) = ""
     If iws.Cells(RowNo, "H") = "" Then
     ws.Cells(irow, "E") = iws.Cells(RowNo, 2)
     irow = irow + 1
  End If
  RowNo = RowNo + 1
  Loop

  Do Until iws.Cells(RowNo, 2) = ""
     If iws.Cells(RowNo, "O") = 0 Then
     ws.Cells(irow, "G") = iws.Cells(RowNo, 2)
     irow = irow + 1
  End If
  RowNo = RowNo + 1
  Loop

  End Sub
```

Comment: You're not resetting your RowNo between do loops so it's picking from where you left off which would be when it's empty and since you check criteria at the top, the loop won't execute. On that note you should reset `irow` as well. Instead of calling to the worksheet to find the row of a range you specify, you could just set them equal to the row number. i.e `irow = 7` and `RowNo = 2`

Comment: Thank you, it now works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way to loop would be:

```
irowE = 7
irowG = 7
RowNo = 2

Do Until iws.Cells(RowNo, 2) = ""
    If iws.Cells(RowNo, "H") = "" Then
        ws.Cells(irowE, "E") = iws.Cells(RowNo, 2)
        irowE = irowE + 1
    End if
    If iws.Cells(RowNo, "O") = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(irowG, "G") = iws.Cells(RowNo, 2)
        irowG = irowG + 1
    End If
    RowNo = RowNo + 1
Loop
```

Having 10 different variables for 10 lists may seem like a pain, but it will greatly speed things up since you will only loop through your input sheet once.